# How to log linenumber and function name in typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, logging

I am using pino for logging. As typescript gets converted to js its showing the line numbers of javascript file.
What is the straight forward approach to achieve this?

This are the things I am looking for in my logs
[time]-[loglevel]-[filename]-[linenumber ]-[msg]

Comment: Are you generating [source maps](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#sourceMap)?